# Define default maven settings.xml for all new projects on intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Intellij sometimes behaves as dumbJ when it relates to re-defining global settings for all future projects.

I mean, you click file -> settings, and because of the name SETTINGS you might think those are global settings and not just related to this specific project that is open... but indeed many of those settings will only apply for that specific project you are looking into. It is the case with maven settings

I go: `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven`

then i click override maven settings file, then i select the maving settings file i use to all projects on my computer, it automatically refines the local repository variable [good] i click save and we are good to go.

some weeks later when i get to create a new project I GOTTA DO ALL THAT AGAIN, and while this is simple [just few clicks] it is absurdly annoying, and i always lose a few minutes on that because I create a new project every few months, so i copy the pom from my previous project and it wont work... the intellij will say pom wont compile or something and i keep thinking how the hell is that not working if it works in the other project... is just after a few minutes that i remember that i need to do all this setup non-sense cuz intellij is to dumb to save it as a global setting.

MY QUESTION IS:

HOW TO DEFINE THE MAVEN SETTING FILE FOR ALL FUTURE PROJECTS USING INTELLIJ?

Comment: Why not define it in the maven install or user home directory independent of IDEA (https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)?

Comment: Yes, just edit ~/.m2/settings.xml and do no configuration in IDEA -- you want thew same results when you run maven at the command line anyway.

Comment: For "new projects", in intelliJ there is also `File>New Project>Settings for New Project...` !;) Which does exactly, what you demand... "Project templates" sounds also interesting/more structured ..

Comment: @tgdavies my local maven installation isn't in that folder... if i run mvn on terminal it loads stuff from a completely different directory. but the idea is good... although not ideal since this way i need to keep track of changes in two places